# C program doesn't print output terminal

Tags: c, printf

This is a program to store all possible combinations of given array in the array `ans[][]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ingredients = 10;
int ans[10][10];
int x = 0;

void makeCombination(int arr1[], int data[], int st, int end, int index, int r);

void CombinationDisplay(int arr1[], int n, int r) {
    int data[r];
    makeCombination(arr1, data, 0, n - 1, 0, r);
}

void makeCombination(int arr1[], int data[], int st, int end, int index, int r) {
    if (index == r) {
        for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
            ans[x][j] = data[j];
        x++;
        return;
    }
    for (int i = st; i <= end && end - i + 1 >= r - index; i++) {
        data[index] = arr1[i];
        makeCombination(arr1, data, i + 1, end, index + 1, r);
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr1[ingredients], i;

    for (i = 0; i < ingredients; i++)
        arr1[i] = i;
    int n = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]);

    for (int r = 0; r < ingredients; r++)
        CombinationDisplay(arr1, n, r);
    
    for (i = 0; i < ingredients; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            printf("%d", ans[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It should store all the combinations in an array `ans` and print it. However, it does not show any errors, nor output in the terminal.

Comment: When I run your program I get some output...

Comment: like 0000000000.... infinitely?

Comment: no. I get stuff like: 0
01
012
0123
01235
012456
0134567
02345678
123456789

Comment: thats the correct output! so i have problem in my compiler?

Comment: It can also be that the program has undefined behavior. What output would you expect for `int ingredients = 2;` ?

Comment: like in a printf statement(which would be 2?) or just the declaration(no output)?

Comment: `int ingredients = 10;` --> `int ingredients = 2;` Which output do you expect then?

Comment: would be the latest value which is 2?

Comment: what do i do then?

Comment: You debug you program step by step. You can use a debugger (e.g. gdb) and single step the program. I you don't have a debugger, you can add `printf` statements in the program.

Comment: Here is a hint for you: https://ideone.com/JaD8fI Look at the block I have inserted (Look for NOTICE NOTICE)

Comment: As you can see from the linked code, your variable `x` is reaching the value 10. So you access the array out of bounds. That's undefined behavior. Anything can happen from there.

Comment: Any reason you simply didn't move `void CombinationDisplay()` below `void makeCombination()` and eliminate the need for the additional forward-declaration (prototype) for `void makeCombination()` above it?

Comment: @Dikesh: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `int ans[10][10];` is not large enough for all combinations of 10 elements: there are 2<sup>10</sup> possible combinations (subsets of a set of 10 elements).
- printing initial subsets of subsets would produce many duplicates.
- a recursive approach is not as simple as an iterative approach for this problem.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define INGREDIENTS 10  // must be in the range 1 to 30 for 32-bit int

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < (1 << INGREDIENTS); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < INGREDIENTS; j++) {
            if (i & (1 << j))
                printf("%u ", j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```